# ¿Cómo obtener un rango de fechas disponible en una lista sin generar traslape?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Tengo una lista de rangos de fechas que tienen una fecha Inicial y una fecha Final, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es crear un nuevo rango de fecha que no genere traslape, es decir que la fecha inicial del nuevo rango no se encuentre dentro de alguno de los rangos de fechas de la lista o la fecha final del nuevo rango no se encuentre dentro de alguno de los rangos de fechas de la lista, ejemplo:
lista de rangos.

```
Fecha inicial = 01-12-2020 12:01:01 Fecha final = 01-12-2020 13:01:01
Fecha inicial = 01-12-2020 14:01:01 Fecha final = 01-12-2020 16:01:01
Fecha inicial = 01-12-2020 17:01:01 Fecha final = 01-12-2020 18:01:01
```

Un rango valido sería:

```
Fecha inicial = 01-12-2020 16:02:01 Fecha final = 01-12-2020 16:02:02
Fecha inicial = 01-12-2020 11:01:01 Fecha final = 01-12-2020 11:01:02
```

Un rango no valido sería:

```
Fecha inicial = 01-12-2020 15:01:01 Fecha final = 01-12-2020 16:02:01 (La fecha inicial esta dentro del segundo rango de ejemplo)

Fecha inicial = 01-12-2020 12:00:59 Fecha final = 01-12-2020 12:02:01 (La fecha final esta dentro del primer rango de ejemplo)
```

Los nuevos rangos pueden ser incluso del orden de milisegundos, después de mucho investigar no he encontrado la forma de hacer esto usando c# (por lo menos no de una forma optima).

Comment: Hola, una vez tuve ese dilema con el tema de horarios para salas de reuniones, una idea de hacerlo podría ser convirtiendo las fechas a milisegundos (obtener enteros) y luego trabajar en base a estos usando vectores.

Comment: Saludos Diego, interesante escenario, ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: @fredyfx encontré que esto se puede trabajar con la librería Time Period Library for .NET (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET), lo que se debe hacer es crear un objeto del tipo TimePeriodCollection, que recibe por constructor una lista de TimeRange, cada objeto de esta lista es un rango de tiempo no disponible, después se crea objeto tipo TimeGapCalculator<TimeRange> y se llama el método GetGaps que retornará un objeto ITimePeriodCollection con cada uno de los rangos disponibles.

Comment: Todo lo que hayas intentado, inclúyelo en la pregunta, por favor :D

Comment: Puedes convertir las fecha a ticks, que devuelve un entero. Y después hacer el trabajo sobre esos enteros. Como vas a tener una lista de fechas que tiene un inicio y un final, te sugiero que use array multidimensional. Y proceso sería, recorrer todo tu array de rangos, si el ticks generado no está entonces lo añades a tu nuevo array.